# PyQt QWidget destructor error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'path'`

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging, pyqt

I use a custom widget inheriting from `QWidget`. This widget may use an online resource: a picture I download from the internet and store in a local file before displaying it in a `QLabel` instance.

When the user closes the window I want the local file to be deleted so I changed the destructor to:

```
def __del__(self):
    if os.path.isfile( self.pictureFilename):
        os.remove( self.pictureFilename)
```

I have:

```
import os
```

at the beginning of my script. Strangely, when the main application closes I get the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/home/XXX/XXX/XXX.py", line 103, in **del**
>
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'path'

It looks like the library gets garbage collected before the destructor gets called. I do not see how to fix that.

Comment: And line 103 is the `os.path.isfile()` call above?

Comment: Can you give us a little more code which we can run to reproduce the behavior?

Comment: @Suever: thank you trying to help, here is the last version of the file: https://github.com/vnherdeiro/transfermarkt-api/blob/master/PlayerWindow.py (I deleted a line so now the error message points at line 102)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the github code, the problem seems to be that when the widget is closed, the Qt application terminate and sys.exit() is called, so probably the module is garbage collected before`__del__` call.

there:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication( sys.argv)
    url = "http://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/cristiano-ronaldo/profil/spieler/8198"
    ex = PlayerWindow( url)
    sys.exit( app.exec_())
```

To avoid the problem I suggest to use the `closeEvent(event)` form QWidget http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#closeEvent

replace yours `__del__` function with this:

```
def closeEvent(self, event):
    if os.path.isfile( self.pictureFilename):
        os.remove( self.pictureFilename)
    del self.profile
    del self.pictureLabel
```

As a general rule you should try to avoid using `__del__` to automatically finalize object with garbage-collection without `del object` begin called explicitly in your code.

Comment: Thank you very much for the input, indeed it fixes the issue. Will remember to use `closeEvent` next time ;)

Comment: And even *with* `del object` - all `del` does is to delete a reference (like doing `object = None`), there still is no guarantee when (and if at all) `__del__` will be called.